# Error 1 Unable to copy file when compiling

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, compilation

Whe i try to compile my project, i get this error

> Error 1   Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\oneForce.pdb" to
>   "bin\Debug\oneForce.pdb". Access to the path
>   'obj\Debug\oneForce.pdb' is denied.   oneForce

Can anybody help me on how to rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all who contributed

in the `obj` folder of the project, i renamed the debug folder, the reason being that i tried to deleted it, but windows won't let me, saying the folder is not empty. So i suspect file curruption and simply renamed the folder.

that solved the problem

thanks all.

Comment: This does make it seem likely that the file handle was in use by another process. Windows will allow you to rename a file that's in use, but it won't allow you to modify or delete it. Renaming it just skirts the problem and allows VS to create a *new* file at the location it wants to.

Comment: i did not rename thje `.pdo` file causing the problem, but the folder

Comment: Irrelevant; that still bypasses the problem. Windows created a new folder that does not already contain a PDB file.

Comment: As i said before, the file was not in use by another process, if that is what you are still saying, i restated my system just to be sure, and VS is the only program i started, just to be sure

Answer (score 2):

Something else probably has the obj\Debug\oneForce.pdb file open.  Do you have the project open in multiple copies of Visual Studio?

Otherwise find out what has the file open.  See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/6607/tool-to-determine-what-has-locked-a-file) for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the application you're compiling isn't running when you're building the project or the DLL being built (if it's a DLL) isn't referenced by any application that is running.
You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to search for your application and possibly kill the process that is using it if closing it normally didn't work.

Comment: The PDB file is in use, not the application. That's not necessarily the same thing. Also, don't just kill processes aimlessly. If possible, close them correctly. Process Explorer should be primarily a tool for diagnosing the problem, not solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is trying to modify the automatically-generated PDB file (containing debugging information) located in your project's `Debug` folder, but something is preventing it from doing so.

Make sure that you have full write privileges to the folder where your project is saved, and that the PDB file is not in use by a debugger (such as another instance of Visual Studio).

The error message tells you the path relative to your project/solution directory that the file is located in; this is where you should check to ensure that you have read/write access:

```
<SolutionDir>\bin\Debug\oneForce.pdb
```

And you can use an application like Sysinternals' [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to check and see what other applications might have that file open.

Finally, if all else fails, try closing Visual Studio and restarting it. That usually fixes any issues where file handles remain open when they should have been closed.

Comment: i only have one instance of VS running, and also i have restarted VS many times without solution, even restarting my system.

Comment: @Smith: If you've restarted the computer, then it's impossible that any process is still holding a handle to the file.  So it seems more likely that you do not have full write privileges to the folder where your PDB file is being stored. Try to copy or create a file in that folder using Windows Explorer and see if that works. Also keep in mind that accessing that folder might require administrative privileges, which Visual Studio will not have by default running under a standard user account. Try launching VS as an administrator by right-clicking on the icon and using the context menu option.

Comment: i have been running this project for more than 2 months now, and i don't experience any errors. it just started today

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your app is used by another process.  Make sure it is not running.  Open task manager and check if it not there.

Restarting VS or machine should help, but you need to figure out what is holding your pdb.  Could be performance analyzer, or DotTrace.

Comment: It's not the app, it's the PDB file. It's likely that there's another debugger (perhaps another instance of Visual Studio?) that is using the file.

Comment: Yes.  Restarting VS or computer will solve this issue.  But what is holding this PDB needs to be figured out, so it will not happen again.

Comment: The suggestion to restart VS was the very last paragraph of my answer, before which I suggested a host of possibilities to aid in tracking down the culprit. I'm not sure what that comment was supposed to mean; I didn't say to restart the computer in my previous comment. The point is that the PDB file is separate from the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533) (from sysinternals) to discover the process (or application) that is locking the pdb file.